# Get RadioButton value Razor MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have list of radio button with true and false values. I want to get the value on change click event so I can use it for displaying conditional label. If its true; I'll show a label if its false different label. Its a list of items so I am looping through it..

here is what I have so far:

**Model:**

```
public List<bool>answerValues { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<td> 
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.answerValues[i], true, new { id = 
    "TrueValueID", @onclick = "buttonValue()"}) True

   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model=> model.answerValues[i], false, new { id = 
    "FalseValueID", @onclick ="buttonValue()" }) False 
</td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
      function buttonValue(e) {
          alert(e.value);
      }

  </script>
```

In the Controller - Action method (Get), I want to get the true/ false value so I can show/hide based on values.

I am not familiar with Razor / MVC. any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `this`, should use `buttonValue(this)`:

```
<td> 
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.answerValues[i], true, new { id = 
    "TrueValueID", @onclick = "buttonValue(this)"}) True

   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model=> model.answerValues[i], false, new { id = 
    "FalseValueID", @onclick ="buttonValue(this)" }) False 
</td>
```

**In action:**

```js
function buttonValue(e) {
  alert(e.value);

  if (e.value === 'true') {
    alert('it is true');
  } else {
    alert('it is false');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="true" onclick="buttonValue(this)" />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="false" onclick="buttonValue(this)" />
```

> I want to get the true/ false value so I can show/hide based on values

Radio button return `on` if checked, so show label if value return `on` else show another label. Also you can set `value` for radio button like `<input type="radio" value="true"...` or boolean.

Comment: Thank you so much! the keyword "this" did the trick.how can I pass this value from the View to Controller. I just typed the button name in the Action (get method) in the Controller but it didn't recognize it.??

Comment: I used your code for the if statements its always printing "hmmm" despite selecting true???

Comment: @Warda Are you sure `alert(e.value);` return `on` ?

Comment: yeah i copied your exact code but I noticed in your scenario you only have one radio button. with me i have two one for true other for false. currently its always showing the "hmm" message which means its skipping the first if statement??

Comment: @Warda Kinda yes. look, `on` means it is `checked`, you can not uncheck radio button manually, so you never see `off` or `false` but you say it return `Hmmmm` this mean your radio button not return `on` or `true` something else is wrong. I can't say anything without see your result but it is impossible `alert(e.value);` return `on` but you see `Hmmmm...` odd.

Comment: @Warda Check updated snippet in my answer, is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, Exactly!! Thank you so so so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you.

**Razor Code**

> here we can set common class on radio button to bind on change event
>   in js.

```
<td> 
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.answerValues[i], true, new { id = 
        "TrueValueID", @class="rdbtnanswervalue"}) True

       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model=> model.answerValues[i], false, new { id = 
        "FalseValueID", @class="rdbtnanswervalue" }) False 
    </td>
```

**Js Code**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".rdbtnanswervalue").on("change", function () {

        // for current value
        alert($(this).val());

        // for all radio button with same class uncomment below code.

        //$(".rdbtnanswervalue").each(index, ele)
        //{
        //    // get value and perfom action acordingly.
        //    alert($(ele).val())

        //}
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use name attribute for all radio buttons.

and then in JQuery

```
$('input:radio[name=RADIO_NAME]').change(function () {
        var value = $('input:radio[name=RADIO_NAME]:checked').val();
        switch(value).....

    });
```